# Unit Testing Backpropagation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, neural-network

I'm writing a class library for Backpropagation. I was not following the principles of TDD, but still I want to write some unit test for it. My problem is that I don't know how should I test it.
My only guess is to compute the deltas for the weights manually to have something to compare the results to, but that seems not right, or does it?

So: I would compute the deltas in Excel in one scenario, and than test that scenario. Would that be a valid test?

Thanks.

Comment: You should start with a very simple test problem with known results. For example, the XOR problem as described here. http://www.mind.ilstu.edu/curriculum/artificial_neural_net/xor_problem_and_solution.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing backpropagation algorithms is really important because it's really common for them to have subtle bugs. E.g. the gradients are off, but close enough the network can still sort of learn.

You just use the finite differences method. For each parameter (or a random parameter or whatever) you add a very small value to it. See how much the error changes divided by the amount you changed the parameter, and see if that matches your gradient.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be something similar to what I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by solving a simple test problem with easily verifiable results such as the XOR problem as described in [this document](http://www.mind.ilstu.edu/curriculum/artificial_neural_net/xor_problem_and_solution.php).

Comment: I thought of that too, but I don't think that if the network can solve the XOR problem that necessarily means that the calculaton is correct, or do you think that to be enough?

Comment: At least it will point you to some good direction. The idea is to get an initial baseline result. This will give an idea on whether you are doing it right.